# how to send arabic sms with at-command in text mode (not pdu)

Tags: sms, arabic, at-command, pdu

Is it possible to send arabic sms with at-command in text mode (not pdu) and get a delivery report?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use AT mode?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what the device supports. The AT interface itself is ASCII only, so if you want to do anything other than ASCII text you need a device that provides you a way to put Arabic text over that interface - effectively an encoding scheme, at which point you might as well be using PDU mode anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You could put the modem in HEX mode with `AT+CSCS="HEX"`, turn on delivery report with `AT+CNMI` command, and encode your message in unicode format for `AT+CMGS` command. Each character should be represented by four hexadecimal digits.